# Converting pseudocode for max subarray into working Java code

Tags: java

I have been tasked with converting some pseudocode to working Java code and I would like someone to review my code for correctness.

The pseudocode is as follows:

```
Algorithm MaxsubFaster(A):
Input: An n-element array A of numbers, indexed from 1 to n.
Output: The maximum subarray sum of array A.
S0 ← 0 // the initial prefix sum
for i ← 1 to n do
    Si ← Si−1 + A[i]
m ← 0 // the maximum found so far
for j ← 1 to n do
    for k ← j to n do
        s = Sk − Sj−1
        if s > m then
            m ← s
return m
```

My code is as follows:

```java
public static int maxSubFaster(int[] array)
    {
        Integer S[] = new Integer[array.length];
        Arrays.fill(S,0);

        //initial prefix sum
        S[0] = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++)
        {
            //S_i = S_i-1 + A[i]
            S[i] = S[i - 1] + array[i];
        }
        //maximum found so far
        int max = 0;
        for (int j = 1; j < array.length; j++)
        {
            for (int k = j; k < array.length; k++)
            {
                //s = S_k - S_j-1
                int s = S[k] - S[j - 1];
                //if s > m, m <- s
                if (s > max)
                {
                    max = s;
                }
            }
        }
        return max;
    }//end maxSubFaster
```

The algorithm seems to work, but any pointers or corrections would be great!

Comment: Is there any part of this in particular that you are unsure of?

Comment: Yes, the first 2 statements of the algorithm to be exact; that is, using the Integer array as a means of modeling the pseudocode. I could not think of another way to do this, so i'm curious if there is a more efficient method of modeling.

Answer (score 2):

Your translation is pretty faithful to the already low-level pseudocode but you could:

- The pseudocode talks about an array of *numbers* and not *integers*, but that is just a simple type change, and doesn't affect the logic at all
- copy `array.length` into variable `n` near the top, and use `n` throughout as the original code does,
- remove the initial filling of `S` with 0's, since your first loop will overwrite them anyway (and that was not in the original code)
- change `max` to `m`, and `array` to `A`, but you could argue this makes your code more readable

This probably isn't the point of the exercise, but it is possible to solve this problem with a single loop that scans through the array just once, for a more efficient solution.

Comment: Thank you for your input! The first 3 points are very valid and I was wondering if I should change them. You are correct about the point of the exercise; the idea is to take 3 different algorithms from slow, faster, to fastest and convert them to runnable code so I can perform big O analysis.

Comment: Another question for you; in point 4, did you mean change S to not fill with zeros?

Comment: Point 3 has been so edited.